# Put a wild-card search on a string of varying length?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string that can be 3 different lengths (10, 11, and 12).  If the full string is entered, I do not want to do a wild card search, for example, if `abc1234567` was entered and this was the max length, I would not want to search on `abc1234567%`, but if it was not the max length, I would want to wild-card it.

How much does this effect performance, especially if you are joining on strings?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question really is: do you actually have a performance problem? Have you looked at execution times and query plans in SSMS to see the effect of different queries? If so, what variations have you tried and what were the performance differences?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
 WHERE AnotherField LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(MyField) <> 10 --or some other number
                    THEN MyField + '%'
                    ELSE MyField END
```

But performance wise `LIKE MyField +'%'` should be a smaller operation performed per row. If a string is of max length there's no false positives it could return since there are no characters that exceed it.

Comment: I know I can do this, but if the max length for the particular string entered is actually 10, I don't want to add the `%`

Comment: I'm going to say it before someone else does. Using string operations will prevent any indexing from being used.